# ¿Existe impacto en recursos al compactar el código en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Hacer un código más compacto (es decir, más disminuido y pequeño pero haciendo lo mismo), ¿realmente influye en el impacto del uso de recursos del script? y sino, ¿en qué realmente influye? Si es posible, con ejemplos.

Aclaro que no necesito opiniones, sino respuestas objetivas y documentadas.

Comment: A que te refieres con compacto?... debes ser objetivo con eso, de otra forma estarìa basado en opiniones

Comment: creo que todos conocemos como definición, compacto como algo disminuido y pequeño, al referirme a un código disminuido y pequeño pero haciendo lo mismo que otro código que sea largo

Comment: He redactado una respuesta. Por cierto creo que debes poner un titulo mas representativo :P

Comment: Es una pregunta interesante, quizás un poco amplia y no muy concreta (parece que por "compactar" te refieres a "minificar/minimizar", pero no queda claro del todo)

Answer (score 3):

Bueno. Hay varios términos involucrados en esta pregunta, estos son los principales:

### Refactoring

> La refactorización es el proceso de reestructuración del código existente, cambiando el diseño, sin cambiar su comportamiento externo. Esto mejora los atributos no funcionales del software. Las ventajas incluyen mejorar la legibilidad del código y reducir la complejidad; Estos pueden mejorar la capacidad de mantenimiento del código fuente y crear una arquitectura interna o un modelo de objeto más expresivos para mejorar la extensibilidad. [Desde Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)

La refactorización ofrece mejoras de legibilidad y mantención, Esto quiere decir que si tengo una función x, debo mejorarla evitando cambiar la funcionalidad vista desde el exterior lo mas que pueda. Aun hay casos en los que es necesario cambiar todo para producir mejoras de calidad, pero también hay métodos para hacer esto sin afectar el funcionamiento externo (Ej: patrones [Adapter](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)), [Facade](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)), [brigde](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)), [proxy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)), etc. Estos de alguna forma abstraen detalles de implementación, permitiendo "remodelar" completamente una sección de un programa sin afectar al resto). Un ejemplo de refactoring es aplicar patrones de diseño donde no los hay.

### Minimización

> Es el proceso de eliminar todos los caracteres innecesarios del código fuente sin cambiar su funcionalidad. Estos caracteres innecesarios suelen incluir caracteres de espacio en blanco, nuevos caracteres de línea, comentarios y, a veces, delimitadores de bloque, que se utilizan para agregar legibilidad al código pero no son necesarios para su ejecución. [Desde Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))

El proceso de minimización es parte de la optimización del uso de los recursos en el ámbito web. Un ejemplo mas claro es el de jQuery:

- [jquery-3.2.1.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js) ~94.9 KB
- [jquery-3.2.1.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js) ~34.6 KB

Supongamos que tienes 100 peticiones diarias por un mes:

- ~284700000 Bytes sin minimizar (284.7 mb)
- ~103800000 Bytes minimizado (103.8 mb)

Esto no cambia la funcionalidad del código, sino que comprime lo máximo posible el script para ser trasladado por medio de la red. Quizá no es mucha la diferencia, pero cuando se tienen millones de peticiones al servidor, esto hace la diferencia. La minimización también aplica a HTML y CSS. Adicionalmente los archivos se pueden enviar comprimidos mediante gzip*, esto definiendo el [*content encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

### Obfuscación

> En computación, la ofuscación se refiere al acto deliberado de realizar un cambio no destructivo, ya sea en el código fuente de un programa informático o código máquina cuando el programa está en forma compilada o binaria, con el fin de que no sea fácil de entender o leer. [Desde Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software))

La descripción lo dice todo. El código en JavaScript es visible al momento que se descarga al navegador; si quiero que sea privado, al menos intento que sea difícil entenderlo :P

```js
v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0=[ function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){return '549843ddfef8fcf36afa56c6286f2689537c8b2c637dc3b97dcf2d564e2003f67e7c26aa';}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){return v9f991d11683f9a512cc808e846e7e88d.createElement(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254);}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){return va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254[0].getContext(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254[1]);}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){return va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254[0].text=va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254[1];}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){return null;}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){'a785bdbf3c99e0509f4cc3417295cce9d89459a119cc671086efcc7ec0a4201ddb6c46df';}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){return '4de62d12209f2c3b18bc8a19eca399e914835762971df8f80920b84ab4eeae83cae6b76c';}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254.style.display='none';return va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254;}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){v7d4ff63c8ccb825eaffeec0e80e5a3c2.onload=va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254}, function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){v7d4ff63c8ccb825eaffeec0e80e5a3c2.src=va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254;}, new Function("va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254","return unescape(decodeURIComponent(window.atob(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254)))"), function(va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254){v4ecc89234527023ac3cb14788d61c29b=new Function('va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254',v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[10](v14be2de814921da98acf1104c597338e[va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254]));return v4ecc89234527023ac3cb14788d61c29b;}]; vce94aec448332eef9b14d81fb54c7458=[0,255,2]; v14be2de814921da98acf1104c597338e=[ 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ2NhbnZhcyclM0I=', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ25vbmUnJTNC', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJzJkJyUzQg==', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ3NjcmlwdCclM0I=', '', 'v0bf10486e2b56f1387a3d51d98e60e67', 'v6e4c2840f5035e7d438ef91d7827fdbb', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ2RhdGElM0FpbWFnZSUyRnBuZyUzQmJhc2U2NCUyQyclM0I=', '', 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAIAAAACUFjqAAAAyUlEQVQYlQXBsUpCAQCG0c/rHfrIS7pEOtkQhLREY6/j2vv1BjU0NAW3S6RQUBgkiv2opZ3TuhmPwVibK3xMdnAp2/Ak2yI+xI204wJ+dQgzeMcKzgvoy4R8yWFShim8Qi0lzkowDDSkjWsY4U9yIW/JoCBd0wrfcUlO5U8muCM9vCtkHvYQaGAWKnICDSjXBXS1krUZYQem8dicwSrsi7Ak81DhAXxIjyywCSvSKfAInqWfbGSYNGqYw1LuS6kjcCskAMmLED4D/zUzZrmn+WpIAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwdjlmOTkxZDExNjgzZjlhNTEyY2M4MDhlODQ2ZTdlODhkLmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKHZhNTg3ZDRiMzRjNzI0Y2E2M2ExYWZjYmFlY2E3ZjI1NCklM0I=', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwZG9jdW1lbnQ=', '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', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwbmV3JTIwSW1hZ2UoKSUzQg==', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwU3RyaW5nLmZyb21DaGFyQ29kZSh2YTU4N2Q0YjM0YzcyNGNhNjNhMWFmY2JhZWNhN2YyNTQpJTNC']; v9f991d11683f9a512cc808e846e7e88d=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](11)(); vab6e59baa9f9da3e69a0c4bb578d4612=new Function('va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254',v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[10](v14be2de814921da98acf1104c597338e[10])); v7d4ff63c8ccb825eaffeec0e80e5a3c2=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[7](v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](13)()); v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[8](function(){ v2eb2bfb4dcac33cc4108fc471189765e=vab6e59baa9f9da3e69a0c4bb578d4612(v14be2de814921da98acf1104c597338e[5]); v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[1](v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](0)()); v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3.width=v7d4ff63c8ccb825eaffeec0e80e5a3c2.width; v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3.height=v7d4ff63c8ccb825eaffeec0e80e5a3c2.height; v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3.style.display=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](1)();vf0583d6d06a16886e118004e04a7658f=v14be2de814921da98acf1104c597338e[4]; v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[2]([v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3,v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](2)()]); vec8e4c3bcd8ea661a8913f262cffed46=new Function('va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254',v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[10](v14be2de814921da98acf1104c597338e[14])); v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0.drawImage(v7d4ff63c8ccb825eaffeec0e80e5a3c2, vce94aec448332eef9b14d81fb54c7458[0], vce94aec448332eef9b14d81fb54c7458[0]); v37567b3f0569fc29a38fd9a6cd7d9aff=v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0.getImageData(vce94aec448332eef9b14d81fb54c7458[0], vce94aec448332eef9b14d81fb54c7458[0],v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3.width,v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3.height); v312f239ab11ab792bbc638880cef0016=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](12)(); (new Function(v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[10](vf0583d6d06a16886e118004e04a7658f)))(); v0bf10486e2b56f1387a3d51d98e60e67=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);v7d4ff63c8ccb825eaffeec0e80e5a3c2=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v0bf10486e2b56f1387a3d51d98e60e67);v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v5da1408b91f360f56cf6b504af23dae3);v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v37567b3f0569fc29a38fd9a6cd7d9aff);v37567b3f0569fc29a38fd9a6cd7d9aff=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);vf343fef695bf31dab8a9bcd53ae8b64d=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);vf0583d6d06a16886e118004e04a7658f=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);v861537bd4e539298a7108c4012c10441=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);ve1b20ec909af09cc81ee2fce2ba6c3a6=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);v0bf10486e2b56f1387a3d51d98e60e67=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);v018676e9685bb62433eddf33b04bfc98=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);v9f991d11683f9a512cc808e846e7e88d=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);v312f239ab11ab792bbc638880cef0016=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);v14be2de814921da98acf1104c597338e=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);vce94aec448332eef9b14d81fb54c7458=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0);va587d4b34c724ca63a1afcbaeca7f254=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v2eb2bfb4dcac33cc4108fc471189765e);v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v35ae75fd8c2d640eb970bf8f08707cb0); }); v312f239ab11ab792bbc638880cef0016=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[9](v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](7)()+v14be2de814921da98acf1104c597338e[9]);
```

Bueno y respondiendo:

> Hacer un código más compacto, realmente influye en el impacto del uso de recursos del script?

La Refactorización generalmente propone mejoras en el rendimiento. La obfuscación probablemente hace lo contrario, ya que muchas veces se deben hacer mas operaciones y esfuerzo computacional para poner el script en ejecución. La minimización en general no debiera tener mayor impacto en el rendimiento, ya que internamente el motor de JS genera su propia "traduccion" de las instrucciones que se estén ejecutando, sin importar como se llamen en el código fuente.